# What is a more efficient way to compare and filter Sequences (multiple calls to a single call)

Tags: scala

I have two sequences of Data objects and I want to establish what has been added, removed and is common between `DataSeq1` and `DataSeq2` based upon the `id` in the Data objects within each sequence.

I can achieve this using the following:

```
val dataRemoved = DataSeq1.filterNot(c => DataSeq2.exists(_.id == c.id))
val dataAdded = DataSeq2.filterNot(c => DataSeq1.exists(_.id == c.id))
val dataCommon = DataSeq1.filter(c => DataSeq2.exists(_.id == c.id))

//Based upon what is common I want to filter DataSeq2
var incomingDataToCompare = List[Data]()
      dataCommon.foreach(data => {incomingDataToCompare = DataSeq2.find(_.id == data.id).get :: incomingDataToCompare})
```

However as the Data object gets larger calling filters three different times may have a performance impact. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same output (i.e. what has been removed, added and in common) in a single call?

Comment: Yeah use **Sets** to do the comparisons and filters. - `val data1Ids = DataSeq1.iterator.map(_.id).toSet` - `val data2Ids = DataSeq2.iterator.map(_.id).toSet` and then all the questions become basic operations on **Sets**, take a look to the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html).

Comment: I am not sure I understand your code. I don't see any usage of `dataRemoved` and `dataAdded`. Why do you calculate them?

Comment: I use `dataRemoved` and `dataAdded` for logging purposes at a later point in my code but this didn't seem related to my main question so I didn't include it

Comment: For this use case I need to end up with two `Seq[Data]` or `List[Data]` containing only Data objects with the same ids
e.g. `DataSeq1BasedOnCommonIDs` and `DataSeq2BasedOnCommonIDs`.

In my above code this is `dataCommon` and `incomingDataToCompare`

Comment: Maybe you should think about a different way to log your data, and maybe to save performance like that. If you need only `dataCommon`, and the computations are expensive, consider to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, quite possibly not, unless you are going to add some additional features into the system. I would guess that you need to keep a log of operations in order to improve the time complexity. Even better if that log will be indexed both by the order in which the operation has occurred and by the id of the item that was added/removed. I will leave it to you to discover how such a log can be used.

Also you might be able to improve time complexity if you are going to keep the original sequences sorted by id (or a separate seq of sorted ids, you should probably be able to do that incurring a logN penalty per a single operation). This seq should be of type vector or something, to allow fast random access. Then you can probably iterate with two pointers. But this algorithm's efficiency will depend greatly on whether the unique ids are bounded and also whether this "establish added/removed/same" operation will be called much more frequently compared to the operations that mutate the sequences.